# How to define a cmp function used in sort() in a class that can receive additional, object-specified information?

Tags: c++, class

I have a class called `Polygon`, basically structured like this:

```
class Polygon {
public:
    Polygon(int _n): n(_n) { p = new Point2D[n+1](); }
    int n;
    Point2D *p;
    Point2D center;

    void initCenterPoint() {
        double x = 0, y = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
            x += p[i].x;
            y += p[i].y;
        }
        center = Point2D(x/n, y/n);
    }
    void sortVertices() {
        std::sort(p,p+n,less);
    }

    /** Basically this is what I want to do. 
        The sortVertices() method needs the compare method below, while 
        the compare method need to access public member 'center' in the
        object. How can I implement this?
    */

    bool less(const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b) {
        return a.x + b.x - center.x > 0;
    }
}
```

I want to implement `sortVertices()` function, but **the compare function `less` needs to access member `center`**, which differs in different objects. I cannot put it in the class, or give it another parameter, nor can I declared it as `static` or `friend` due to my requirements and  the restrictions in C++.

So how can I implement this? Thanks.

**Update:** Added details about the situation.

And sadly we are not using C++11 so lambda expressions cannot be applied.

Comment: It would help if you could post some code illustrating the problem.

Comment: Can you perhaps show show us  what would the lessthan() function might look like without worrying about access/permissions/etc?

Comment: Your `less` function cannot be used to sort anything, because the results are the same if you swap `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a functor instead of `less`. Each `Polygon` would hold an instance of the functor, and the functor would have a reference to `center`:

```
class Polygon {
public:
    int n;
    Point2D *p;
    Point2D center;
    struct Less
    {
      Less(const Point2D& p) : point_(p) {}
      const Point2D& point_;
      bool operator()(const Point2D& lhs, const Point2D& rhs)
      {
        // implement comparison using point_
      }
    };
    Less lessCmp_; // instantiate in constructor init list

    void sortVertices() {
        std::sort(p,p+n, lessCmp_);
    }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but still puzzled about how to implement this. Would you please be more specific? I have updated the question and added more detailed code.

Comment: @renfei I cannot be more specific than this. Which part are you having problems with? By the way, your `less` function is broken. You cannot use that criteria to sort.

Comment: should probably be `const Point2D & p` in the constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes the `less` function is actually more complicated than that, it's just a (bad) illustration of how `center` is used. Now I think I have understand the idea: we assign things to `point_` instead of `center`, because the functor can access `point_`.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas can help solve your problem. You essentially want to create a function "less" that somehow has knowledge of a variable that is not passed in as a parameter. Check out [this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html) (especially the "variable capture with lambdas" section) if you don't understand what the code does.

```
//myLess is not a member function
bool myLess (Point2D x, Point2D y, Point2D center) {
//Your sorting code here
}

...

//inside your class definition 
void sortVertices() {
  auto less = [] (Point2D x, Point2D y) {return myLess(x,y,center);};
  std::sort(p,p+n,less);
}
```

Comment: the myLess function can be a static method of Polygon instead of a global function.